# Could not open port 'COM10': PermissionError when connecting Function Generator

Tags: python, serial-port

Hi :) I am trying to control a function generator from a py script but always get the error `"could not open port 'COM10': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)"`

1. I work in Windows, function generator HM8150
2. 

[The driver FTDI is installed and I see the port in device manager:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibV9P.png)
3.
[I can see the ports with the script, but I can not access it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPDPD.png)

It looks like a problem with the permissions to access the port. Please, any ideas?

What I already tried:

I do not have any other program accessing the port.
I removed the connection, restarted the PC, closed every application.
I have tried with Windows 10 and 11.
I changed the number of the port.

I expect to find a way to access the Port

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running Python or your script as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

The function generator has 2 ways of connecting to the PC. I was using the USB port, which did not work. I changed to the RS-232 and is now accessible :)